# Customizing Azure ML Studio data profiles

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-machine-learning-service

Azure's ML studio allows us to add data assets, and create data profiles that describe these assets. The profile includes a wealth of data quality metrics including min/max values, % missing, stdev etc.
However, I don't see an option to customize these profiles with our own code. Is this something that is permitted?

I have tried out the UI-driven approach, but unable to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Azure Machine Learning studio does not provide an option to customize data profiles with your own code.

[image]